# Google Cloud Platform's Text Search (New) API does not return "photos" key in response body, even though photos of the place exists

Tags: google-cloud-platform, postman, google-places-api

I am currently testing the **new** [Text Search (New) API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/text-search) through Postman API Platform, and managed to authenticate and receive responses successfully.

However, I find that the "**photos**" key in the response body seems to be missing. How can I find the key in the response body of the **New** Places API?

Context:

- Set the request headers `X-Goog-FieldMask` to * (to get every field)
- Set the request body to:

```
{
    "textQuery": "vegetarian food near Paya Lebar MRT",
    "regionCode": "sg",
    "minRating": 4,
    "maxResultCount": 20,
    "rankPreference": "RELEVANCE"
}
```

- Response:
  [image: First part of response]
  [image: Second part of response]

I am aware that this is still on beta, therefore I am unsure if this an expected behaviour, a bug, or still a feature in-development. Is there anywhere I can see a timeline and status for this API implementation?

Also, Would all the fields `X-Goog-FieldMask`, specified in [Text Search (New) API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/text-search) docs guaranteed to be supported in the future?

Thank you very much for your help!

In the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/text-search), I saw that `places.photos` is one of the possible field in `X-Goog-FieldMask`:

```
Specify one or more of the following place data types:

..., places.location, places.photos, places.plusCode, ...
```

However, setting `X-Goog-FieldMask: places.photos`, gives an empty results:
[image]

I have also verified that the first result (on the first photo) has at least a photo display:
https://www.google.com/maps?cid=4095281016176447978
[image]

Photos are also working if I were to use the **old** way (using the Place ID -> Get Places Details -> Get Places Photos):
[image]

Comment: Hi! I'd suggest that you [file a support case](https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support) or [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=1815671)

Comment: Same here, I contacted support they said they are planning to release this functionality to GA and open up access to photos at the end of this month (Oct 2023)

Answer (score 0):

Seems they deployed this now, it's working for me:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:searchText' \
--header 'X-Goog-Api-Key: YOUR_API_KEY_HERE' \
--header 'X-Goog-FieldMask: places.displayName,places.photos,places.googleMapsUri' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "textQuery": "Eiffel Tower"
}'
```

With response:

```json
{

  "places": [

    {

      "googleMapsUri": "https://maps.google.com/?cid=10222232094831998944",

      "displayName": {

        "text": "Eiffel Tower",

        "languageCode": "en"

      },

      "photos": [

        {

          "name": "places/ChIJLU7jZClu5kcR4PcOOO6p3I0/photos/AcJnMuEBW95lJSICR5KsWDrzNkKePHffESYIWaY0yqbnm7VsBtG0ADag9vwlFBN42-yGZiG0z-rEtGrVUdH1P1hU8LSET2qAOlc6oT8O55VLQlNWTZbr-wiILeQ3cv1itDeq6jXHQH3IyP9vth3zefjRuOHDA7f2pgT9zUVc",

          "widthPx": 1000,

          "heightPx": 660,

          "authorAttributions": [

            {

              "displayName": "1PLUS VIETNAM",

              "uri": "//maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100968979814345776530",

              "photoUri": "//lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/ALV-UjXLaDbibv0nq2sjhPP9EY6Gf_TrJibVerZwYs_DMvb6goMR=s100-p-k-no-mo"

            }

          ]

        },
...
```

Then we are extracting the photo_reference which is present in the `name` param of each photo after the `/photos` which in this example is:

`AcJnMuEBW95lJSICR5KsWDrzNkKePHffESYIWaY0yqbnm7VsBtG0ADag9vwlFBN42-yGZiG0z-rEtGrVUdH1P1hU8LSET2qAOlc6oT8O55VLQlNWTZbr-wiILeQ3cv1itDeq6jXHQH3IyP9vth3zefjRuOHDA7f2pgT9zUVc`

And finally use the following URL to get the image:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=
AcJnMuEBW95lJSICR5KsWDrzNkKePHffESYIWaY0yqbnm7VsBtG0ADag9vwlFBN42-yGZiG0z-rEtGrVUdH1P1hU8LSET2qAOlc6oT8O55VLQlNWTZbr-wiILeQ3cv1itDeq6jXHQH3IyP9vth3zefjRuOHDA7f2pgT9zUVc&sensor=false&maxheight=1600&maxwidth=1600&key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE

Don't forget to replace YOUR_API_KEY_HERE with your api key.